# Cannot see my entire ScrollView on Storyboard anymore without giving up scrolling

Tags: uiscrollview, storyboard, scroll, autolayout

Something weird happened today. I have an app with a UIScrollView of 2000 pixels long. When I built it (using the Storyboard), I disabled AutoLayout, set the simulated size of the embedding ViewContoller to 'FreeForm', set the vertical size of the ViewController to 2000 and dragged in a UIScrollView which automatically filled its entire ViewController. After creating the outlet and setting the ContentSize of the UIScrollView to 2000, this worked. In the app I could scroll all the way to the bottom of the UIScrollView, and at the same time I could see the entire 2000 pixel high ScrollView in the Storyboard.

This morning, I accidentally hit the 'AutoLaoyout' tick mark again. As a result, scrolling no longer worked. When I disabled AutoLayout again, scrolling was *not* recovered. The only way I could get scrolling working properly again, was setting the vertical size of the UIScrollView to 600. However, this way I can only see the upper part of it in my StoryBoard, which is very inconvenient.

What am I missing here? How can I make sure I can see the the UIScrollView in its entire length in the Storyboard without disabling the scrolling, just like before?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: make sure your UIView and the UISCrollView have both autoresizing enabled in the Size Inspector. Just activate all the guides for both of them. Then set both at the same size in the Size Inspector, e.g. 320 x 1200 and don't forget [self.Scroller setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320,1200)] or something similar. All good!